# Writing to a certain CSV row/column, using header names

Tags: python, csv

I have a bunch of CSV files that I want to convert into a single CSV file, in which each row represents one of the original CSV files. I'm using the CSV package, and I've already figured out how I can read entries from my original CSV files. I also have a template CSV file that only contains one row, that is, the header (containing column names such as 'Price', 'Date', and 'Quantity') for my single CSV that I want to create.

```
with open ('TemplateFile.csv', 'w') as TemplateFile: 
    TemplateFileWriter = csv.writer(TemplateFile, delimiter=';') 
    # I already have references to all the files I want to access in the variable fileList
    for f in fileList:              
        with open(f, 'r') as InputFile:             
            InputFileReader = list(csv.reader(InputFile, delimiter=';'))                        
            # This is where I store the 'Price' variable.           
            tmp = InputFileReader[3][3]
```

Now, what I would like to do is to have a convenient way of storing `tmp` in a certain row in `TemplateFile`, at the same column that "Price" happens to be. I've been reading up on the CSV package and both `write` and `DictWrite` but I just find the documentation impossible to follow.

What I would like to have is ultimately something like this for my last line:

```
TemplateFileWriter[myPrefferedRow]['Price'] = tmp
```

Am I trying to achieve something impossible here or is this possible to do with the CSV package?

Comment: What do you mean by "storing tmp"?

Comment: @JoelCornett Sorry, I had made changes to my post without updating everything. I was referring to the last variable of the first code block, which now is there :)

Comment: Ah. Can you provide example inputs and outputs? Just 5-10 lines of CSV should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv.reader` and `csv.writer` only read and write rows, so like you used `list(csv.reader(...))` to read the rows and put them into a list of lists, you can create a list of lists (or dicts) for your output, modify entries as you like, and then use `TemplateFileWriter.writerows()` to output it to the file.

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) package has a loadtxt function that might do what you want...

```
import numpy as np
def foo(fname):    
    yourdata = np.loadtxt(fname, delimiter=';')
    return yourdata[3,3]
```

Comment: This one seems to do exactly what the line `InputFileReader[3][3]` does in my code, or am I missing something here?

Comment: I have no experience with cvs reader, but that function should give you the third element of the third row in an ASCII file. Headers marked by '#' are automatically ignored.